# If $f$ is not primitive, then it is not irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

This is the beginning of a proof from *Algebra, Chapter $0$* by Aluffi.

[image]

I am not sure why this statement is true. If $f$ is not primitive, then the gcd of its coefficients is not $1$. But what if the content of $f$ is a unit. Then we can factor $f$ but it would still be irreducible. What am I missing?

Comment: Presumably when it begins with the hypothesis that $f\in R[x]$ is irreducible, it means irreducible in $R[x]$. Note GCD in a UFD is only defined up to units, so the content being a unit and the content being $1$ are essentially the same thing. In order for the content to not be $1$ mod units, it would have to be a non-unit.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly echoing the comment above, but I think what you're missing is the definition of primitive. The definition of primitive is not that the content is $1$, it's that the content is a unit.